# If statement conditions getting triggered by content inside of the if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a piece of code that is checking to see if a variable exists and if it doesn't, it sets the variable. The code is:

```
if (typeof myVariable == "undefined") {
  console.log("Inside the if statement");
}
```

When the variable exists, it doesn't enter into the if statement and everything is good. However, when I change the code to:

```
if (typeof myVariable == "undefined") {
  var myVariable = "";
}
```

I get an issue where the if statement triggers every time, even if the variable has already be defined and it gets overwritten.

Is there a reason that the condition for the if statement is being triggered by virtue of changing what is inside of it?

Comment: The `var` statement scopes to the function, not the block. In other words, in JavaScript, it's as if the `var` came before the `if`, no matter where you physically typed the letters `v` `a` `r`.

Comment: Read [all about hoisting](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+hoisting+explained&oq=javascript+hois&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.3585j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: ... And [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet) on function scope and hoisting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to be aware of the scope of your variables. In this example myVar is scoped to the foo method.

```
function foo(myVar) {
    if(typeof myVar == 'undefined') {
        myVar = 'defaultValue';
    }

    console.log(myVar);
}

foo(); => 'defaultValue'

foo('bar'); => 'bar'
```

I suspect that you are running into issues where you may be defining "myVariable" in one scope and then expecting to carry over to another scope. The only way this would occur is if "myVariable" is in the global scope.

Answer (score -3):

should be:

```
if (typeof myVariable == undefined) {
  console.log("Inside the if statement");
}
```

No quotes around undefined.

Comment: not only is this wrong (the `typeof` unary operator always returns a string), it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: You should read the docs of [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)